# Kubernetes error pulling of local registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to setup a local registry for local development with kubernetes.

I do this by: `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2`

I then build and tag a docker image:

```
docker tag apiservice localhost:5000/apiservice
```

push it to the registry:

```
docker push localhost:5000/apiservice
```

In my k82 deployment definition:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: apiserver
        image: localhost:5000/apiservice:latest
```

This is is the error:
[image]

What do I need to change to use minikube and a local docker container registry?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the registry on your machine's Docker or the Docker inside minikube? These are separate instances of DOcker, you can make them with:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

as explained here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#reusing-the-docker-daemon

Then you will be able to pull Docker images from your local machine inside minikube.

Comment: I'm running a registry on my machine's docker not inside minikube. So the command eval.. is enough?